# Is it possible to flash out of the way of a spell that occurs almost instantly?

Tags: league-of-legends

I have fairly fast reaction times and am able to flash out of the way of say an Ashe or Jinx ulti if I don't see it early enough to right click my character away.

Some champs have spells that occur **almost** instantaneously, but within a certain range. For example, Blitzcrank can only grab people within a certain range of him/her/it.

It's sometimes predictable when Blitz is going for the grab, so I was wondering if it was possible to flash out of the way of his grab to escape it?

Comment: Flashing to avoid skill shots like blitz grab, thresh hook, ahri charms is a very important skill, but it does typically require reading your opponent.

Comment: I am pretty sure that whether or not you can flash/dodge an ability is based on whether it is targeted ability or a skill shot. Abilities that are used by clicking on a champion are not dodge-able (Vi Ult, Taric Stun) while abilities that are used in a direction or area (Blitzcrank grab, Nami Ult) can be dodged (via flash or otherwise)

Comment: @Bob2Chiv Not entirely correct.  You can dodge some clickable skills like Poppy E.

Comment: You can flash away from any skillshot in the game to avoid it. Flashing over a morgana/lux Q is incredibly rewarding. Practice it in a custom with a friend! There's a video somewhere on the web of a Poppy flashing over an Ashe ult and it looks incredibly cool, because Ashe's ult is so long that Poppy had to time it perfectly to flash over it. Wish I could find it.

Answer (score 3):

In League of Legends there are 3 major type of spells. Targeted, Self-Cast and Skillshots.

**Targeted** abilities are locked on the target. If the target moves or flashes away, the ability will still hit the target (Like Annie's Q or Ranged Basic Attacks)

**Self Cast** or Stance abilities only work on yourself, you cannot target them on a teammate (but it can still benefit teammates, such as Sona's Basic Abilities)

**Skillshots** are aimable by the caster, but their travel path is *constant*. If one is coming your way you can flash or just dodge it. Blitzcrank's grab is a skillshot, so you can dodge it.

**However**, you cannot flash away from the hook once it lands on you, similarly to Darius' E. There is an exception to this - Ezreal's E (a blink/dash) is able to prevent being pulled, while visually making Blitzcrank's arm extend even further (which is so funny)

Comment: The reason ezreal - and tristana also - can escape blitz's grab is because of the small cast time on their movement abilities. If the blitz lands his grab before they finish casting they still get away. Doesn't work that way with thresh's hook though.

Comment: Your description of Targeted is not correct for all abilities.  Only some.  I described in my example above that you can actually dodge Poppy's E.

Comment: That's because Poppy's E has special interations with the code. It's targetted when she starts it, but its a skillshot after it "fires". It's a point and click on a unit (to avoid being used as a gap creator), but once an unit is selected it will dash to the place where that unit is. You can flash out of it due to that

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **Yes**

You can flash a blitz hook easily. You just have to time it correctly.

You can even dodge an Ezreals Ultimate by flashing (even towards him).
Many players do this. They are in a tight skirmish and they see an opportunity to be agressive or re-engage and flash the skillshot to do so and finish off an opponent.

It's all about timing and reactions.

Answer (score 1):

A number of skills can be flashed from to dodge them. Any skill shot can be flashed away from to dodge it with proper timing. Most other skills (targeted ones) cannot be flashed away from, as they will follow you (i.e. Caitlyn ultimate, Malphite seismic shard, etc) but certain skills can with proper timing (i.e. Alistar headbutt, and select others). However there can be good reason for flashing from targeted abilities, as if cait ults you, you can flash behind a team mate and the ult will hit them instead, provided they stand in the path the ult is traveling. Also flashing behind a yasuo wall or braum unbreakable shield will cause any particle from a targeted ability to be destroyed one the wall. However since while flashing, until the animation completes, you are considered to still be in the place you are flashing from, some targeted abilities, skill shots, and even auto attacks can still hit. Examples of this are singed fling being used at the same time the person flashes can cause the person to be flung back even after the flash finishes. Similar interactions exist between ahri's charm, other abilities, and auto attacks.